# Eclipse library jar files in Android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, libs

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0c8H.png)

In the picture you can see the libs folder and it contans two sub folders and a jar file named unity classes. I want to merge this project with my android studio project so in this case i want to copy my eclipse project java files, res folder and libs and everything. I copied everything in my android studio project but confused that how to copy libs folder from eclipse to android studio. I know that there is a compile ' ' option in build.gradle but what to write their? I am a newbie so please tell me what to do? I just want these libs folder to be written in android studio

Comment: Check on google _Migrate eclipse project to Android Studio_

Comment: Sir as i mentioned i want to merge eclipse project  in my android studio project thats why i want these libs folder to be merge in android studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a libs folder

- -Add your jars to this folder(Copy and paste them).
- -Right click on the jar-> Synchronize 'your.jar name'

Finally just add below code in your gradle, This will add all the jars

```
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

You can also add separate jar by :

```
compile files('libs/yourJarName.jar')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer finally. Its simple and i just have to add this line

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```